# How to create a 3D "X" in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, 3d, scenekit

I am trying to make tic tac toe in 3D just to get more practice with scene kit. I made the board and the O but cant think of the way to make the X. Need some ideas to create the X.

Comment: Have you looked at `SCNText`?

Comment: Thank you it worked. How do I change the color of the text?

Comment: Never Mind I just have to use materials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that

1. Use `SCNText` to create the geometry from a text and font
2. Use `SCNShape` to create the geometry from an extruded 2D Bézier path
3. Use a 3D authoring tool and import your geometry into SceneKit
4. Use `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement` to programmatically build a completely custom `SCNGeometry`